# Flutter Classes Objects are accessing private fields without getters

Tags: flutter, dart

***Hi, I am quite a bit confused, why main method can access private fields.***

```
void main() {
  A obj = A();
  obj._b = 'a';
  print(obj._b);
}


class A {
  String _b;
}
```

**output:- a**

please see the screenshot that theres no error.[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Unlike Java, Dart doesn’t have the keywords public, protected, and private.

There's no keyword or annotation so you can declare a field/function as private on class level, but you can declare a field/function as private member on lib scope.[Read](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility)

So lets come to your question, your main method is able to access a field started with '_' because there are in the same package. Create a new file and move your class to that file, and you will not be able to access the private member.

So,

> identifiers that start with an underscore (_) are visible only inside the library.

Comment: thanks developer, but it also happens when i create the 2 classes in a same file but in flutter, now i cannot understand that if i create 2 classes in same files and 2 classes in different files, whats different with that.

Comment: because flutter allow only declaring private members on package level (dart file) not class level

Answer (score 0):

In dart `_` (underscore) sign is encapsulating fields on namespace level, not class level. For class level encapsulation ( still not private but protected ) consider using `@protected` annotation for the fields or move your class to a separate file.

I think this is the answer of you question right @umar_baloch.